# How to use a function of one type, in a function of another type?

Tags: c

I have one function that getting printing a menue and returning a choice. And another function to calculate 2 numbers that im getting from the user. Now, the calculation is depanding on the choice return from the first function, and im dont really know what is the right way to use 2 different type of functions together...this is both functions:

```
float calc(float number1, float number2)

{
    float answer;
    int operand;
    operand =get_choice();// problemmmm

}

char get_choice(void)

{
    char choice;

    printf("Enter the operation of your choice:\n");
    printf("a. add        s. subtract\n");
    printf("m. multiply   d. divide\n");
    printf("q. quit");

    while ((choice = getchar()) != 'q')
    {

        if (choice != 'a' || choice != 's' || choice != 'm' || choice != 'd')
        {
            printf("Enter the operation of your choice:\n");
            printf("a. add        s. subtract\n");
            printf("m. multiply   d. divide\n");
            printf("q. quit");
            continue;
        }
    }
    return choice;
}
```

I got an error saying "implicit function of get_choice is invalid in C99"

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you mean by "problemmm"?

Comment: By the way, you should try to find a way to avoid having to write the printfs twice in your `get_choice` function. Its usually a bad idea to have duplicated code since you need to always remember that if you change one part then you also need to change the other.

Comment: is it a proper way to use it? i got an error saying "implicit function of get_choice is invalid in C99" sorry for being unclear @missingno

Comment: you right, i will rewrite if, thanks @missingno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That implicit function error probably means that the compiler doesn't yet know about the `get_choice` function by the time it reaches the line when it gets called. You can fix this by either.

1. Changing the order you write your functions in. Write get_choice before the calc function
2. Add a declaration for the get_choice function before the calc function. The declaration would be just the function name and type, without the code:

   ```
   char get_choice(void);
   ```

If you are wondering what the message was about, in C89 undeclared functions were implicitly assumed to return an integer. C99 is stricter and forces you to always declare functions but the error message still refers to the C89 style implicit declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to perform different calculation depending on the operator? You can use function pointer to achieve it. Namely, write a dictionary that maps each choice('a', 's', 'm', 'd') respectively to operation(add, subtract, multiply, divide) of a function pointer type `float (*)(float, float)` .

BTW, if you haven't declared `get_choice`, you should put its function body BEFORE `calc`.
The other problem is `get_choice(void)` return `char`, but you declare operand as `int`.

Comment: i will learn about pointers only next chapter..thanks though @HuiZheng

Comment: i have no idea why that happened ..:/! @HuiZheng

Answer (score 0):

> I got an error saying "implicit function of get_choice is invalid in C99"

In C, you need to *declare* a function before you call it; otherwise the compiler doesn't know what the return type is supposed to be.

You can do one of two things.  One, you can declare the `get_choice` function before you call it:

```
float calc(float number1, float number2)
{
    float answer;
    int operand;

    char get_choice(void);

    operand =get_choice();// problemmmm
}
```

Alternately, you can switch the order in which the functions are defined, so that the `get_choice` function is defined before it's called (my preference).

Answer (score 0):

I C/C++,  It is required for a compiler to know the type (size) of an identifier, but not a particular value it holds (in case of variables). This is called [forward declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration)

In your case, the compiler doesn't know `get_choice()` when you call it from `calc()`.